# figuring out the possible attributes of an object

Tags: python, gdata

regarding this code from [python-blogger](https://github.com/codeape2/python-blogger/blob/master/blogger.py#L36)

```
def listposts(service, blogid):
    feed = service.Get('/feeds/' + blogid + '/posts/default')
    for post in feed.entry:
        print post.GetEditLink().href.split('/')[-1], post.title.text, "[DRAFT]" if is_draft(post) else ""
```

I want to know what fields exist in `feed.entry`  but I'm not sure where to look in [these docs](http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/pydocs/gdata.html) to find out.

So I dont just want an answer. I want to know how I should've navigated the docs to find out for myself.

Answer (score 3):

Try dir(field.entry) 
It may be useful for your case.

Answer (score 2):

It's a case of working through it, step by step.

The first thing I did was click on service on the link you sent... based on `service = feed.Get(...)`

Which leads here: http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/pydocs/gdata.service.html

Then looking at .Get() it states

```
Returns:
  If there is no ResultsTransformer specified in the call, a GDataFeed 
  or GDataEntry depending on which is sent from the server. If the 
  response is niether a feed or entry and there is no ResultsTransformer,
  return a string. If there is a ResultsTransformer, the returned value 
  will be that of the ResultsTransformer function.
```

So guessing you've got a GDataFeed - as you're iterating over it:, and a quick google for "google GDataFeed" leads to: https://developers.google.com/gdata/jsdoc/1.10/google/gdata/Feed

Comment: that makes sense, but your google results are for a javascript class. This seems to be the right class - http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/pydocs/gdata.html#GDataFeed  ... but even with those docs, it's not clear to me how to figure out what `.entry` does.

Comment: another thing... you mean `feed = service.Get()` not as you wrote it.

Comment: One's allowed a brain burp now and then surely @thequietcenter. I agree it's lousy documentation though - but at least there is *some* documentation. Another way to narrow it down would be to do a type(feed) and see what class that returns, then do a bit more googling on that name and see if anything else turns up. A Python wrapper will be based very close to the actual interface, so then look at the google api's and see if explanations are more thorough or understandable there...